# Hard to interpret dereference operands in inline assembler code

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, dereference

*tl;dr at the bottom.*

Other than programming a bit on the System z years ago, I have no experience with Assembler. Furthermore, as far as I know, there is such a thing as type information in Assembler - but here none is given, so apparently the types are implicitely inferred from the C++ variables given to the code.

I need to get rid of it. Means I have to discern what it does. Apparently this is harder than I thought:

Case one:

```
  push eax
  push ebx
  push ecx
  push edx
  push esi
  push edi

  mov esi, data
  mov edi, screen
  xor eax, eax
heightloop2: // do {
  mov edx, width1
  neg edx
widthloop2: // do {
  mov eax, [esi + edx*8] // screen[b] = data[b]
  mov ecx, 4[esi + edx*8] // screen[b] = data[b]
  mov [edi + edx*8], eax
  mov 4[edi + edx*8], ecx

  add edx, 1 // b += 1
  js widthloop2 // } while(b)

  add edi, destpitch // screen += SCREEN_WIDTH
  add esi, datapitch // data += datapitch
  dec counter
  jnz heightloop2 // } while(a)

  //emms

  pop edi
  pop esi
  pop edx
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  pop eax
```

Case 2:

```
  push eax
  push ebx
  push ecx
  push edx
  push esi
  push edi

  mov esi, data
  mov edi, screen
  xor eax, eax
  mov ecx, transcol
heightloop: // do {
  mov ebx, 0
  mov edx, width1
  neg edx
widthloop: // do {
  mov ax, [esi + ebx*2] // screen[b] = data[b]
  add ebx, step // b += 1

  cmp eax, ecx // Check for transparent color
  je trans

  mov [edi + edx*2], ax
trans:
  add edx, 1 // b += 1
  jnz widthloop // } while(b)

  add edi, destpitch // screen += SCREEN_WIDTH
  add esi, datapitch // data += datapitch
  dec counter
  jnz heightloop // } while(a)

  //emms

  pop edi
  pop esi
  pop edx
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  pop eax
```

The comments are not mine, they are what I have to work with.

Both have similar sets of inputs:

```
unsigned char * data, screen
uint32_t * palette
int counter, datapitch, destpitch, step, transcol, width1
```

Now, as is easily discerned (unless I am mistaken, please correct in that case), the control flow of both cases is equal:

```
do
{
  // int a = 0; // additionally in case 2
  int b = -weight1;
  do
  {
    <work>
  }
  while(++b < 0); // actually ++b != 0 in case 2, but symptoms should be equal
  screen += destpitch;
  data += datapitch;
}
while(--counter != 0);
```

Now, the "work" part differs slightly. There are two things which confuse me thoroughly:

- Both first mov instructions have the same comment - but the dereferences address is calculated differently. How can this fit together? What exactly does the factor do here?
- Case 2 has another mov set with a number prefix in front of the dereference brackets. I was unable to find this idiom in various references I scoured. What does this expression mean?

Unfortunately, the VS2015 debugger emits all values within these code examples as "unsigned int" - I am almost sure that this is incorrect (again, if I am wrong, please correct).

So, concise:

- ***Please verify or correct my inferred control flow.***
- ***Please explain or link to an explanation of these mov instructions.***

---

Using the pointers from @Jester I was able to replace the two cases with this identically performing C++ code:

Case 1:

```
  do
  {
    for(int b = -width1; b < 0; ++b)
      memcpy(screen + b * 8, data + b * 8, 8u);

    screen += destpitch;
    data += datapitch;
  }
  while(--counter != 0);
```

Case 2:

```
  do
  {
    int a = 0;
    for(int b = -width1; b != 0; ++b)
    {
      const uint16_t * const c = (uint16_t*)(data + a * 2);
      if(transcol != *c)
        memcpy(screen + b * 2, c, 2u);
      a += step;
    }
    screen += destpitch;
    data += datapitch;
  }
  while(--counter != 0);
```

Of course, looking at this it is immediately obvious that it can be written more elegantly, but I decided to leave it in this rough state here, so that the transformation is more apparent.

Comment: You don't need to save/restore (push/pop) ALL the registers, only the callee-saved ones for the ABI you're using.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ for some asm info.  eax can always be used without saving/restoring, because it's used as the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor is scaling by element size. As you can see, the first case processes 8 byte units, the second case 2 byte units.

The number outside the brackets is a special case of array syntax.  You can do the same in C, by the way: `5[array]` is the same as `array[5]`. In "normal" intel syntax you just stick the number inside the brackets, e.g. `mov [edi + edx*8 + 4], ecx`.

Comment: So, if I wanted to translate these instructions into C++, they would mean:

Case 1:
`screen[b * 8] = data[b * 8];
screen[4 + b * 8] = data[4 + b * 8];`

Case 2:
`a += step;
if(transcol != 0)
  screen[b * 2] = data[b * 2]`
?

Comment: Roughly, except the code processes **all** bytes of the array item while your C code only processes 1 byte.

Comment: Oh? Even if embedded into the prototype I posted in the OP? How come?

Comment: ... Wait, does that mean that Case 1 somehow processes the indices **from** [b * 8] **till** [5 + b * 8]? So four bytes rather than two bytes with an offset of 4? How?

Comment: At `widthloop2` you can see it loads `eax` and `ecx` which are 4 bytes each, then writes both of those out. Thus case1 processes all bytes from `b*8` to `b*8+7` then in the next iteration it will continue at `(b+1)*8`. Case2 `widthloop` you can see it processes `ax`, which is 2 bytes.

Comment: Ah, understanding dawns. Accepted for correctness and upvoted (if apparently invisibly due to lacking reputation?) for prompt and concise elaboration. Thank you very much.